# Cannot view/create tenants in Google Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity, google-iam

I've got a **GCP project** shared with me with the "project owner" access.
So, I can open and manage the "**Identity Platform**" users.
But **I can't open** the "**Tenants**" page (it's loading infinitely).

So, maybe it requires some **additional roles**, although I'm an owner of the project and I have the following roles assigned:

```
App Engine Admin
Cloud Build Editor
Cloud Scheduler Admin
Environment and Storage Object Administrator
Cloud Datastore Owner
Firebase Admin
Logging Admin
Google Cloud Managed Identities Admin
Admin of Tenancy Units
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin
Storage Transfer Admin
```

Some people also suggest to open the page in incognito mode, but unfortunately it, not my case.

I also have noticed that "Tenants" currently in the BETA stage.
But I'm not sure if it's related somehow.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Does it make sense to use Tenants in Google Identity Platform?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm owner of my project and the tenant work well. You should lack of some permissions (and it's very hard to find information. I'm in contact with the PM, I will try to know more)

About the relevance of tenant, all depends of your use cases. If you have user from different context/customer and you want to manage authentication in different manner according to this context.

If a customer don't pay, you can also deactivate a tenant, and you can disrupt the authentication (and thus the service) until the payment.

Your use case has to make sense, not the technical capabilities.

**UPDATE**

About permission, there is not yet predefined roles and you have to build a custom role for this. [The list of permission are the same as for firebase](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/access-control)

Comment: I got info from PM, I updated the first part of my answer

Comment: I've added all roles from Firebase and a bunch of other roles it didn't help.
I finally end up with adding "owner" role